# Is there a complete list of the types and their properties accessible via Room.lookAt?

Tags: javascript, screeps

The docs aren't very thorough on this point and more detail would be very nice. What are the possible values for type? terrain?

Answer (score 1):

The docs have been updated. But a complete list is still not present.
http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203079011-Room#lookAt

I think creep, terrain and structure is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a complete list of the types and their properties accessible
>   via Room.lookAt?

Nope. Not yet.

> The docs aren't very thorough on this point and more detail would be
>   very nice. What are the possible values for type? terrain?

I think that `type` means the class of the object in question, like terrain, creep, spawn and so on. So I guess for now we have to wait for them to finish writing the docs for a complete list. Speaking of terrain, the docs actually mention only a single kind of terrain (swamp) on the [Room](http://www.screeps.com/docs/Room.php) page:

```
[
    { type: ‘creep’, creep: {...} },
    { type: ‘spawn’, spawn: {...} },
    { type: ‘terrain’, terrain: ‘swamp’} },
    ...
]
```